# Separate show/hide jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, show-hide

I have a problem with a collapsible jquery code.

I'd like to separate some DIVs, but if I click on an element, whichever that is, it opens all of the other elements as well. I have to use more than of these collapsible things (aprox. 40 pieces because there are a lot of versions in one page and I have to save some place). I would like to know how to separate the DIVs from one another. 
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
   $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
 });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
div.panel,p.flip {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #FFCFF9;
 border: solid 1px #fff;
}

div.panel {
 widht: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
 <div class="panel" id="1">
  <p>Fist panel text</p>
 </div>
 <p class="flip" id="1">1st version</p>
 <div class="panel" id="2">
  <p>Second panel text</p>
 </div>
 <p class="flip" id="2">2nd version</p>
```

At first I tried this:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm 
But there was a problem as well; it only shows the content of the first DIV, the rest won't come down. I don't know if I should name the DIVs (as you can see in the code, I've tried that) or not, but if I do, I don't know what's the proper way to do it. Please help me out if you can. Thank you!

Comment: In your code, click on any element with class flip would toggle .panel. What kind of behavior would you like to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JS fiddle with a working version.

https://jsfiddle.net/b3bc4yk6/

The main reason your code was not working is you were not targeting the div you want to expand/contract, you were targeting them all. As you can see from the HTML I have given each panel their own ID.

```
<div class="panel" id="panel-1">
  <p>Fist panel text</p>
 </div>
 <p class="flip" id="1">1st version</p>
 <div class="panel" id="panel-2">
  <p>Second panel text</p>
 </div>
 <p class="flip" id="2">2nd version</p>
```

Also note that an ID should be unique so a flip element and a panel element should not have the same ID.

Now in the jquery we can grab the ID of the flip and target the specific panel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
   $("#panel-" + $(this).attr('id')).slideToggle("slow");
  });
 });
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to remind you that ids need to be unique. In your example there are two elements with id="1" and two with id="2".

You could also wrap each panel / flip combo inside a container div.

Html:

```
<div class="panelContainer">
   <div class="panel">
      <p>Fist panel text</p>
   </div>
   <p class="flip" id="1">1st version</p>
</div>
<div class="panelContainer">
   <div class="panel" id="2">
      <p>Second panel text</p>
   </div>
   <p class="flip" id="2">2nd version</p>
</div>
```

In your js you put a click function for each element with class "flip" to toggle all elements with class "panel".

What you want to do is toggle the panel that corresponds to the flip that was clicked.

Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".flip").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function() {
               $(this).closest(".panelContainer").find(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
            });
         });
       });
    </script>
```

Haven't tested the code, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: closest will try to traverse up the DOM tree and will have the effect of opening the previous panel rather than the panel below the clicked "flip" class.

Comment: Is there any reason to call the each function on the flip elements? Could you not just use $(".flip").click(function() {??

Comment: @David Jones - No reason. Your option works just as well.

Comment: @BobbyC - "get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree." Taken from https://api.jquery.com/closest/

This means that it indeed does not work as I intended but for another reason.

Another option would be to get the closest ".panelContainer" and then "find" the first inner ".panel" inside the panelContainer.

I choose this option due to the fact that if the two elements won't be siblings any more, the code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".flip").click(function() {
      $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: For this you would have to edit the HTML to have the panel after the button. The current state of the HTML would open the wrong panel. For example flip 1 would open panel 2 and flip 2 wouldn't do anything because there is no panel 3.

Comment: Ah , you are right. For some reason I was under the impression "flip" preceded the panel, but it's indeed the other way around. so instead of the .next() using .closest() would be correct.  Petre's answer is correct without the .each() line.